# Popup message and ajax to jquery form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I create a form with PHP and jQuery, I add this in footer of my website, all I need is to display the form results in a popup in the main of my website not in the footer and make this to work without page refresh (with ajax). I add here my entire code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
   <input name="url" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
if(substr( $string_n, 0, 7 ) != "http://" && substr( $string_n, 0, 8 ) != "https://")
$url = "http://".$url;
if(stripos($url,"folder/")>0)
$content = file_get_contents($url);
else
$content = file_get_contents($url."/folder/");
if(preg_match("/Copyright ver\. ([0-9.]+)/", $content, $result))
echo "Your year is : ".$result[1];
else
echo "Sorry cannot determine year";
}
?>
```

Comment: is not exist must be created, but i don't know how, in this moment when I press Check button the page is refresh

Comment: i see that but if I don't have any post.php file? how the ajax will look?

Comment: other way is not exist? I mean without this php file?

Comment: I think you are not clear about `ajax`.. you are posting `url` from that form ok?? and doing something with that url using your php code right?? So if you post that url using ajax than you have to put that php code somewhere na? are you getting what I am trying to say?

Comment: can you make this code for me please, because I can't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

dont forget to put jquery in top of the html page

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Check below solution

//this will be your html file

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input name="url" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
</form>
<script>

    $(function() {
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

create a `post.php` file put your php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
    if (substr($string_n, 0, 7) != "http://" && substr($string_n, 0, 8) != "https://")
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    if (stripos($url, "folder/") > 0)
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
    else
        $content = file_get_contents($url . "/folder/");
    if (preg_match("/Copyright ver\. ([0-9.]+)/", $content, $result))
        echo "Your year is : " . $result[1];
    else
        echo "Sorry cannot determine year";
}
?>
```

Comment: and yes have you inserted `jquery` if no than put jquery??? if yes put `echo 'test';` on the top of post.php and check wether it alerts `test` or not... and than you will get to know

Comment: can you add an example? how to echo 'test';?  I use jquery. thank you

Comment: can you help me with this echo please? I think your code is work but is not display anything

Comment: sorry i don;t understand? how can i show the $result[1]?

Comment: @RobertD You should start with some php and jquery basics.. this won't work like that...

Comment: you add this in your code "success: function(html) {alert(html);}" and this is display only a blank alert window, can you tell me how to put there the $result?

Comment: anything which will be outputted by `post.php` file will appear on alert.. here no output is genetated so you get blank alert...

Comment: this must be the output        $content = file_get_contents($url . "/folder/");
    if (preg_match("/Copyright ver\. ([0-9.]+)/", $content, $result))
        echo "Your year is : " . $result[1];
    else
        echo "Sorry cannot determine year";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80183/discussion-between-robertd-and-nishant-solanki).

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using the code provided, you are still missing some AJAX code. As you have used both the jQuery and JavaScript tags, I wasn't sure if you are using Vanilla or jQuery (my example uses jQuery).

My example will make an AJAX request when the user clicks the submit button. `$your_url` will need to be set to a file which contains your PHP code you specified in the question.

```js
$('#my_button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      text: $('#some_text').val(),
    },
    url: "<?php echo $your_url; ?>",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log($data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  <input name="url" type="text" / id="some_text">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" class="btn btn-primary" id="my_button" />
</form>
```

Your PHP will need to be changed so that it works correctly with this AJAX request. As mentioned in the comments, it seems like you do not fully understand how AJAX works, and how it communicates with PHP. I suggest the following documentation and tutorials:

- [AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [AJAX beginners guide](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)

Comment: hi tommy, thank you for your answer, can you make the entire code for me please?